# Creación de tabla temporal con inserción de datos entra en loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Estimad@s, tengan buen día, estoy creando un `Stored` que se encarga de crear una tabla temporal y luego -mediante una consulta- debe insertar los datos en dicha tabla. Mi problema radica en que esto entra en loop y no se termina de hacer los inserts. Lo que es raro debido a que si yo extraigo esa consulta y la realizo por separado, me trae un registro. Dejo mi `Stored`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Juicios]
    @asesor NVARCHAR(5),
    @varBan INT
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #AuxJuiciosTemp(
        Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
        Solicitud NVARCHAR(10), 
        Titulo FLOAT, 
        CodPlan NVARCHAR(8),
        Nomimal MONEY, 
        ImporteCuota MONEY, 
        CantCuotas INT, 
        Asesor1 NVARCHAR(5),
        Asesor2 NVARCHAR(5),
        ReporteAcumulado_Tipo INT, 
        MesVenta SMALLDATETIME
    )

    DECLARE @Solicitud NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @Titulo FLOAT
    DECLARE @CodPlan NVARCHAR(8)
    DECLARE @Nomimal MONEY
    DECLARE @ImporteCuota MONEY
    DECLARE @CantCuotas INT
    DECLARE @Asesor1 NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @Asesor2 NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo INT
    DECLARE @MesVenta SMALLDATETIME

    IF @varBan = 1
        BEGIN
            DECLARE cursorAuxiliar CURSOR FOR
            SELECT S.ANTITSOL, S.ACNUMSOL, S.PlanCertificado, S.ImporteCertificado, S.ACIDASE, S.Asesor2, PSQL.amvalnomplan, PSQL.ancantcuoplan, S.MesVenta
            FROM Solicitud S 
                INNER JOIN PLANsql PSQL 
                    ON S.PlanCertificado = PSQL.acidplan
            WHERE S.ACIDASE = @asesor
        END
    IF @varBan = 2
        BEGIN
            DECLARE cursorAuxiliar CURSOR FOR
            SELECT S.ANTITSOL, S.ACNUMSOL, S.PlanCertificado, S.ImporteCertificado, S.ACIDASE, S.Asesor2, PSQL.amvalnomplan, PSQL.ancantcuoplan, S.MesVenta
            FROM Solicitud S 
                INNER JOIN PLANsql PSQL 
                    ON S.PlanCertificado = PSQL.acidplan
            WHERE S.Asesor2 = @asesor
        END
    IF @varBan = 3
        BEGIN
            DECLARE cursorAuxiliar CURSOR FOR
            SELECT S.ANTITSOL, S.ACNUMSOL, S.PlanCertificado, S.ImporteCertificado, S.ACIDASE, S.Asesor2, PSQL.amvalnomplan, PSQL.ancantcuoplan, S.MesVenta
            FROM Solicitud S 
                INNER JOIN PLANsql PSQL 
                    ON S.PlanCertificado = PSQL.acidplan
            WHERE S.ACIDASE = @asesor OR S.Asesor2 = @asesor
        END

    OPEN cursorAuxiliar
    FETCH cursorAuxiliar INTO @Titulo, @Solicitud, @CodPlan, @ImporteCuota, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, @Nomimal, @CantCuotas, @MesVenta
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @Asesor1 = @asesor AND @Asesor2 IS NULL
                BEGIN 
                    SET @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo = 0
                    INSERT INTO #AuxJuiciosTemp(Solicitud, Titulo, CodPlan, Nomimal, ImporteCuota, CantCuotas, Asesor1, Asesor2, ReporteAcumulado_Tipo, MesVenta)
                    VALUES(@Solicitud, @Titulo, @CodPlan, @Nomimal, @ImporteCuota, @CantCuotas, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo, @MesVenta)
                END
            IF @Asesor1 = @asesor AND @Asesor2 IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    SET @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo = 1
                    INSERT INTO #AuxJuiciosTemp(Solicitud, Titulo, CodPlan, Nomimal, ImporteCuota, CantCuotas, Asesor1, Asesor2, ReporteAcumulado_Tipo, MesVenta)
                    VALUES(@Solicitud, @Titulo, @CodPlan, @Nomimal, @ImporteCuota, @CantCuotas, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo, @MesVenta)
                END
            IF @Asesor1 <> @asesor AND @Asesor2 = @asesor
                BEGIN
                    SET @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo = 2
                    INSERT INTO #AuxJuiciosTemp(Solicitud, Titulo, CodPlan, Nomimal, ImporteCuota, CantCuotas, Asesor1, Asesor2, ReporteAcumulado_Tipo, MesVenta)
                    VALUES(@Solicitud, @Titulo, @CodPlan, @Nomimal, @ImporteCuota, @CantCuotas, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo, @MesVenta)
                END
            ELSE    
                BEGIN
                    SET @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo = 5
                    INSERT INTO #AuxJuiciosTemp(Solicitud, Titulo, CodPlan, Nomimal, ImporteCuota, CantCuotas, Asesor1, Asesor2, ReporteAcumulado_Tipo, MesVenta)
                    VALUES(@Solicitud, @Titulo, @CodPlan, @Nomimal, @ImporteCuota, @CantCuotas, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo, @MesVenta)
                END
        END

    CLOSE cursorAuxiliar
    DEALLOCATE cursorAuxiliar

    SELECT * FROM #AuxJuiciosTemp
    DROP TABLE #AuxJuiciosTemp
END
```

Estoy seguro de que mi error está en el cursor, pero no termino de entender en qué parte. ¿Alguno ve mi error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que no estás usando fetch para que cargue los valores al dar la vuelta al bucle, por tanto es infinito.

Antes de cerrarlo, hay otra vez un `FETCH cursorAuxiliar INTO`

No obstante, no parece necesario ni declarar el cursor en diferentes ifs, ni probablemente usar ninguna tabla temporal. ya que a priori haciendo un `Case` a la columna de la union de `Solicitud y PlanSql`, y un `row_number` debería de ser suficiente, para la eliminación del mismo. Pero eso no es objeto de esta pregunta.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Juicios]
    @asesor NVARCHAR(5),
    @varBan INT
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #AuxJuiciosTemp(
        Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
        Solicitud NVARCHAR(10), 
        Titulo FLOAT, 
        CodPlan NVARCHAR(8),
        Nomimal MONEY, 
        ImporteCuota MONEY, 
        CantCuotas INT, 
        Asesor1 NVARCHAR(5),
        Asesor2 NVARCHAR(5),
        ReporteAcumulado_Tipo INT, 
        MesVenta SMALLDATETIME
    )

    DECLARE @Solicitud NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @Titulo FLOAT
    DECLARE @CodPlan NVARCHAR(8)
    DECLARE @Nomimal MONEY
    DECLARE @ImporteCuota MONEY
    DECLARE @CantCuotas INT
    DECLARE @Asesor1 NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @Asesor2 NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @ReporteAcumulado_Tipo INT
    DECLARE @MesVenta SMALLDATETIME
    
    DECLARE cursorAuxiliar CURSOR FOR
       SELECT S.ANTITSOL, S.ACNUMSOL, S.PlanCertificado, S.ImporteCertificado, S.ACIDASE, S.Asesor2, PSQL.amvalnomplan, PSQL.ancantcuoplan, S.MesVenta
            FROM Solicitud S 
                INNER JOIN PLANsql PSQL 
                    ON S.PlanCertificado = PSQL.acidplan
            WHERE (S.ACIDASE = @asesor And @varBan = 1)
                or 
                  (S.Asesor2 = @asesor And @varBan = 2)
                or 
                  ((S.ACIDASE = @asesor OR S.Asesor2 = @asesor) And @varBan = 3)

    OPEN cursorAuxiliar
    FETCH cursorAuxiliar INTO @Titulo, @Solicitud, @CodPlan, @ImporteCuota, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, @Nomimal, @CantCuotas, @MesVenta
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO #AuxJuiciosTemp(Solicitud, Titulo, CodPlan, Nomimal, ImporteCuota, CantCuotas, Asesor1, Asesor2, ReporteAcumulado_Tipo, MesVenta)
            SELECT @Solicitud, @Titulo, @CodPlan, @Nomimal, @ImporteCuota, @CantCuotas, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, 
             CASE WHEN   
                    @Asesor1 = @asesor AND @Asesor2 IS NULL
                  THEN 0 
                  WHEN
                    @Asesor1 = @asesor AND @Asesor2 IS NOT NULL
                  THEN 1
                  WHEN 
                    @Asesor1 <> @asesor AND @Asesor2 = @asesor
                  THEN 2
                  ELSE 
                       5
             END , @MesVenta;
            

            
            FETCH cursorAuxiliar INTO @Titulo, @Solicitud, @CodPlan, @ImporteCuota, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, @Nomimal, @CantCuotas, @MesVenta
        END

    CLOSE cursorAuxiliar
    DEALLOCATE cursorAuxiliar

    SELECT * FROM #AuxJuiciosTemp
    DROP TABLE #AuxJuiciosTemp
END
```

Comment: Waw, muchísimas gracias, la verdad es que nunca se me cruzó por la cabeza usar un `CASE` lo cual simplificó muchísimo el código. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Dentro del while debes hacer de nuevo un fetch

Ejemplo:

```
OPEN cursorAuxiliar
FETCH cursorAuxiliar INTO @Titulo, @Solicitud, @CodPlan, @ImporteCuota, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, @Nomimal, @CantCuotas, @MesVenta
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
           .....
           .....
           FETCH cursorAuxiliar INTO @Titulo, @Solicitud, @CodPlan, @ImporteCuota, @Asesor1, @Asesor2, @Nomimal, @CantCuotas, @MesVenta
     END
CLOSE cursorAuxiliar
DEALLOCATE cursorAuxiliar
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Dirían en mi pueblo ¿Por qué tanto brinco estando el suelo tan parejo?

No necesitas usar un cursor para insertar fila por fila a una tabla temporal para luego solo leerla. Eso es un gasto de recursos innecesario cuando todo lo puedes hacer simplemente con una consulta.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Juicios]
    @asesor NVARCHAR(5),
    @varBan INT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Id,
        S.ACNUMSOL AS Solicitud, 
        S.ANTITSOL AS Titulo, 
        S.PlanCertificado AS CodPlan, 
        PSQL.amvalnomplan AS Nominal, 
        S.ImporteCertificado AS ImporteCuuota, 
        PSQL.ancantcuoplan AS CantCuotas, 
        S.ACIDASE AS Asesor1, 
        S.Asesor2 AS Asesor2, 
        CASE WHEN S.ACIDASE =  @asesor AND S.Asesor2 IS NULL     THEN 0
             WHEN S.ACIDASE =  @asesor AND S.Asesor2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
             WHEN S.ACIDASE <> @asesor AND S.Asesor2 = @asesor   THEN 2
             ELSE 5 END AS ReporteAcumulado_Tipo,
        S.MesVenta AS MesVenta
FROM       Solicitud S 
INNER JOIN PLANsql   PSQL ON S.PlanCertificado = PSQL.acidplan
WHERE ( S.ACIDASE = @asesor AND @varBan IN (1, 3))
OR    ( S.Asesor2 = @asesor AND @varBan IN (2, 3));
```